# Can't make methods void

Tags: java, android

When I'm trying to make a userLogin method in a class I want to set a string value if success == "true" but When I make the methods onResponse and onErrorListener void It gives the error:

> 'onErrorResponse('VolleyError') in Anonymous class derived from
>   com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener' clashes with
>   'onErrorResponse(VolleyError)' in
>   'com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener'; attempting to use
>   incompatible return type'

My code:

```
 private void userLogin() {
            RequestQueue requestQueue = MySingleton.getInstance().getrequestqueue();
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) throws JSONException {
                            checkLogin(response);
                            if(success.equals("true")){
                                Login.testt = "signed in!";
                            }
                            else {
                                Login.testt = "error!";
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Login.testt = "error!";
                        }
                    }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(EMAIL, email);
                    map.put(PASSWORD, password);
                    return map;
                }
            };
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }
```

How can I use these methods as void?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriden methods can't be edited. As the name suggests, they can ONLY be overriden

Comment: Well, they can be overloaded, but the return type of overloaded or overridden methods cannot differ. Just to be complete.